# AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi() postToConnection is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, gateway, websocket

I am trying to send a message to a client connected through the socket by using `**AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi() postToConnection**` method. It's working fine in local, but not working in ec2. The only difference is VPC. Is that would be a problem?

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var awsGW = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({
    endpoint: "https://endpoint",
    accessKeyId: "accessKeyId",
    secretAccessKey: "secretAccessKey",
    region: "region"
});

awsGW.postToConnection({
    ConnectionId: 'ConnectionId',
    Data: '{"key1":"msg1","key2":"msg2"}'
}, (err, success) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Socket error', err);
    } else {
    }
});
```

**ERROR:**

```
{ ForbiddenException: Forbidden
    at Object.extractError (/home/ubuntu/git/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)
    at Request.extractError (/home/ubuntu/git/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/rest_json.js:55:8)
    at Request.callListeners (/home/ubuntu/git/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/home/ubuntu/git/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/home/ubuntu/git/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/home/ubuntu/git/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/ubuntu/git/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /home/ubuntu/git/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/git/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/git/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
  message: 'Forbidden',
  code: 'ForbiddenException',
  time: 2019-06-10T07:40:02.214Z,
  requestId: 'f4caef03-8b52-11e9-9cc3-91bfe40b8eb0',
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 37.0834357877396 }
```

Answer (score 6):

I ran into a similar problem and it was because I was using the wrong endpoint.  I was generating it from the `event` object but on a normal API request, so I was getting an endpoint for a different service (the normal API, and not the websocket).

If your websockets service is deployed to a URL like `wss://abcd` then your endpoint should be `https://abcd`.

Comment: Exactly the problem I was having. Using `https` rather than `wss` as the URL is super un-intuitive when you read the documentation (golang: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/apigatewaymanagementapi/) and when you consider that the API Gateway console itself says the WebSocket URL is `wss://...`

Answer (score 3):

In my case, there was just an error/undefined value in the endpoint I was using to instantiate the

```
new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({
    endpoint,
    region,
})
```

Note: endpoint can provided in 2 forms:

- custom domain name+ base path mapping, for example: `wss.my-super-website-with-websocket.com/v1` (where v1 is the configured base path mapping)
- default aws-style url like `https://********.execute-api.us-east-5.amazonaws.com/prod` where prod is the stage configured in API Gateway.

More importantly, for your debugging purposes, if you get desperate, I found out that you can quite easily log the request made by `aws-sdk` to make sure you are making the correct request (using the aws cli to try the request is also a good idea):
`node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\event_listeners.js`

```
function executeSend() {
  var http = AWS.HttpClient.getInstance();
  var httpOptions = resp.request.service.config.httpOptions || {};
  try {
    console.log('event listener execute send', resp.request.httpRequest); // only this line is added
    ...
```

Comment: thank you thank you for explicitly stating the two ws forms. In my case, ws worked perfectly in dev environment but was getting 403 in prod environment with custom domain. The issue was because I was missing the base path mapping (v1), which is NOT provided in the request. So I had to instantiate apigw client with:
``` const isProd = stage === "prod";  const apigwClient = new ApiGatewayManagementApiClient({    endpoint: isProd      ? `https://${domainName}/v1`      : `https://${domainName}/${stage}`, }); ```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me
Source : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-apigatewaymanagementapi/classes/posttoconnectioncommand.html

```
import { PostToConnectionCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-apigatewaymanagementapi";

const input = {
   Data: response,
   ConnectionId: connectId,
};
const command = new PostToConnectionCommand(input);
await client.send(command);
```

Answer (score 0):

403 sounds like you need to update the policies for the IAM role calling your `postToConnection`

In my case I had explicit missing rules, hence I had to attach authorizations for `ExecuteAPI`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "execute-api:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-1:###########:*/*/*/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue - I have Lambda inside VPC in private subnet and there was VPC endpoint for API Gateway but it always returned `403 Forbidden`.

It's weird, but after replacing VPC endpoint with NAT Gateway issue has gone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

I was doing the below

```html
const ENDPOINT = 'abcd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production/';

const client = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({endpoint: ENDPOINT});
```

and I was getting this error

```html
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "Invalid URL",
    "code": "ERR_INVALID_URL",
    "input": "rs4jtt6kp5.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production/",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL",
        "    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)",
        "    at new URL (node:internal/url:611:13)",
        "    at parseUrl (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/url-parser/dist-cjs/index.js:7:38)",
        "    at resolveEndpointsConfig (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/config-resolver/dist-cjs/endpointsConfig/resolveEndpointsConfig.js:14:87)",
        "    at new ApiGatewayManagementApiClient (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-apigatewaymanagementapi/dist-cjs/ApiGatewayManagementApiClient.js:18:72)",
        "    at new ApiGatewayManagementApi (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-apigatewaymanagementapi/dist-cjs/ApiGatewayManagementApi.js:8:1)",
        "    at file:///var/task/index.mjs:5:16",
        "    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)"
    ]
}
```

I just added `https://` ENDPOINT to `https://abcd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production/` and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, ws worked perfectly in dev environment but was getting 403 in prod environment with custom domain. The issue was because I was missing the base path mapping (mine is "v1"), which is NOT provided in the ws request. So I had to instantiate apigw client with:

```js
const isProd = stage === "prod";
const apigwClient = new ApiGatewayManagementApiClient({
   endpoint: isProd ? "https://${domainName}/v1" : "https://${domainName}/${stage}"
});
```